# Cygwin terminal error in running .sh file because of a jar file

Tags: java, linux, unix, jar, cygwin

I am trying to run .jar file for my java code from a .sh shell script file. the jar file name contains "." which is making the Cygwin terminal think it is a directory. Here is the command and the results:

```
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar
```

Result:

> no main manifest attribute, in lib\javax.json-1.0.jar

Then:

> error: package javax.json does not exist
>   import javax.json.Json;

With this mark ^ below the period (right after javax).

How can I solve it? I am working on Windows 10. Thanks!

EDIT:
I have written many forms of the .sh file to get it run, but it won't run. The current one is:

```
# !bin/bash  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar  
javac ./src/TimeTester.java  
java TimeTester
```

Does this look good?
I am getting the following error:

> .\src\TimeTester.java:22: error: package javax.json does not exist
>   import javax.json.Json; (With this ^ below the '.')
>   AND:
>   .\src\TimeTester.java:159: error: cannot find symbol
>                     private static JsonObject getJsonFromString(String jsonStr){

And many similar lines in the error.. Any help?

EDIT 2:
This is my current file:

```
javac -cp ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar ./src/TimeTester.java  
java -cp ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar:./src TimeTester
```

But I am getting:

> .\src\TimeTester.java:22: error: package javax.json does not exist
>   import javax.json.Json;
>                    ^

With With this (^) under the last dot (.Json)

EDIT 3:
The current .sh file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
cd src  
javac -cp '../lib/javax.json-1.0.jar;../lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar' TimeTester.java  
java -cp '../lib/javax.json-1.0.jar;../lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar' TimeTester
```

The first command (javac) works and generates the .class file. BUT, the second command (java) does not work and it gives the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class TimeTester

Your help is really appreciated!

Final EDIT:
Thanks for Jim, the shell script now works. Now I got a java execution error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\in_input\in.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Thanks

Comment: Dot means "current directory" in bash.  Perhaps the script was meant to be run from a particular place in the filesystem?   You could replace "." with the rest of a complete path (maybe /cygdrive/c  or /cygdrive/c/usr) if you can find where the jar file is installed on your system.  It would help if we could see the rest of the bash script.

Comment: @JimLewis I have written many forms of the .sh file to get it run, but it won't run. The current one is:  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar  
cd ./src  
javac ./TimeTester.java  
java ./TimeTester  
  
But still unable to test it

Comment: `Cygwin terminal think it is a directory` That error looks more like a java  error than cygwin error.

Comment: I also tried:  
# !bin/bash  
  
 javac -cp ./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar ./src/TimeTester.java  

java -cp .:./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar TimeTester

Comment: [Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) separators are OS dependent. You are on windows - try a semicolon rather than colon

Comment: @copeg didn't work :(

Comment: @Yano, I recommend updating your original question with the script code and modifications thereof, together with the resulting errors

Comment: @copeg Done, Thanks!

Comment: With the current script, if your `TimerTester` relies on the other jar files (eg `javax.json`) you need to add them to the classpath (as your teeny code snipped in comment above attempts, and presuming they reside in the directory path in the command). I'd recommend removing the middle man (script) until you can correctly run the command on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR*** It is a pain to use Cygwin with programs written for Windows because of the conflicting command-line shell conventions between `bash` and `cmd.exe`.  To compile and run Java programs it is much better to use an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans.

However, if you must...

None of this works because you are trying to pass Linux-style paths to the Windows JVM.  However you seem to have a more basic misunderstanding:

```
# !bin/bash  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar  
java -jar ./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar  
javac ./src/TimeTester.java  
java TimeTester
```

I am surmising that you think the first two statements make the libraries available to the compiler for the third `javac` line.  This is not true, those two lines attempt to *execute* the jar file, which of course fails since the jar does not contain a main class

What you should be doing is providing those two library paths as arguments to the `-cp` option of the `javac` command.

This is where it gets quite tricky, as you are mixing a Linux-style shell emulator with a Windows JVM.  Paths that are intended for the shell must remain in Linux style, while paths that are going to be consumed by the JVM must be converted to Windows format, and path strings for the JVM must be delimited with semicolon (Windows style) instead of colon (Linux style).  That introduces a further complication since the semicolon in Cygwin (Linux) is the delimiter for multiple commands on one line, so the path string must be quoted to prevent the semicolon from breaking things.

Also problematic is the naming of the class to be compiled.  You have not shown us the package declaration of the Java file, but I'm assuming it's in the default package (i.e. there is no package declaration and it's not `package src;`).  In that case you should be in the `src` directory, not one directory above.

Finally, once you specify `-cp`, you must also add the current directory to the classpath on Windows if you want it to be included, otherwise it will not find your newly-compiled `.class` file.

So the compile and execute commands should be

```
javac -cp '../lib/javax.json-1.0.jar;../lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar' TimeTester.java
java -cp '.;../lib/javax.json-1.0.jar;../lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar' TimeTester
```

For simple relative paths the Windows JVM will accept forward slashes, but if you have absolute Linux paths (i.e. `/cygdrive/c/...`, or with the cygdrive path set to `/`, paths like `/c/user/...`) the JVM will not understand them and they will need to be translated using `cygpath`.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. Now the javac works, but the last command does not. I get this error:  
> Error: Could not find or load main class TimeTester  
I will update the post

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to include the current directory in `-cp` as well.

Comment: You ARE AMAZING! it now works.. But I got error from inside my code when specifying the file path as a string. The file is located in the correct place but looks like linux does not see it. My code works perfectly in eclipde/Windows.  
This is the error:  
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\in_file\in.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Please ask a separate question for that.  Be sure to include the code that specifies the file path/name, and also the actual file path/name.  Please also remember to "accept" the answer so it will be found by other people looking for the same problem.

Comment: Also, please don't reply to answers by editing your question.

Comment: Done! Sorry if I broke any conventions as I'm a novice user :)

Comment: Should I change the .sh file for real Linux?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the path string delimiter back to colon (`:`)

Answer (score 0):

None of your 4 commands work:

- `java -jar ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar` does not work because `javax.json-1.0.jar` is not an executable jar file.
- `java -jar ./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar` does not work because `javax.json-api-1.0.jar` is not an executable jar file.
- `javac ./src/TimeTester.java` does not work because your class requires classes from the `javax.json` package to be on the classpath, and you haven't set the classpath. Classes from the `javax.json` package are found in the `javax.json-1.0.jar` file.
- `java TimeTester` does not work because the compilation failed.

To fix all that, remove the first two lines, and specify the classpath on the other two lines, e.g.

```
javac -cp ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar ./src/TimeTester.java
java -cp ./lib/javax.json-1.0.jar:./lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar:./src TimeTester
```

Notice that you also had to list `./src` on the classpath when executing your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am getting errors with the dots (.)  
> .\src\TimeTester.java:22: error: package javax.json does not exist  
> import javax.json.Json;  
With this (^) under the last dot (.Json)